# Error in importing sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

I was using sklearn library for many days, but sudunly today I cant import sklearn. There is some problem in sicpy library which I can't find solution for.
And this problem started exatly after I ran `apt-get update`

Here is the error I am getting.

```
   Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 45, in <module>
    from scipy.special import expit     # SciPy >= 0.10
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 643, in <module>
    from ._ellip_harm import ellip_harm, ellip_harm_2, ellip_normal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/special/_ellip_harm.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._ellip_harm_2 import _ellipsoid, _ellipsoid_norm
  File "scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.pyx", line 5, in init scipy.special._ellip_harm_2 (scipy/special/_ellip_harm_2.c:7330)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from ._bvp import solve_bvp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_bvp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import splu
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 84, in <module>
    def bicg(A, b, x0=None, tol=1e-5, maxiter=None, xtype=None, M=None, callback=None):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_threadsafety.py", line 59, in decorator
    return lock.decorate(func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_threadsafety.py", line 47, in decorate
    return scipy._lib.decorator.decorate(func, caller)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'decorate'
>>>
```

Solutions I tried:

- Restarting pc
- Reinstalling sklearn
- Reinstalling sicpy
- Banging my head to pc

Please help soon, as I need it to complete my semester project.

Comment: I suggest to install Anaconda first and then try installing all the required packages through it.

Comment: Ok let me try that.

Comment: Have you run also 'upgrade' by any chance? Any way, in general I would refrain from using system's Python for any work. Do yourself a favour and create a virtual environment (virtualenv). For exactly the reason you just described :). Anaconda is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update python-decorator.
Looks like dependency bug.

Comment: I just copied decorate file and replaced my old one. That also worked. But its same as updating. Thanks.